# What is a matrix and what can it do?

Tags: android, matrix

I am trying to move an image in Android on touch and drag. I came across Matrix while looking into this. Would someone please explain what a matrix is, and what I can achieve with it in Android?

Also, when I apply a matrix to an image, what happens to it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrix is a class in Android framework that stores values which give information on how to transform an image, for example translate or scale.

If you want to drag an image, you can display image as an ImageView, and calculate the difference between x and y coordinates of the first and last position of finger that is touching the ImageView. Then you create a new Matrix object and call a method postTranslate with those x and y values on it. Then you call setMatrix method on the ImageView and the image on screen will move.

Take a look at https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView, a project where ImageView is extended to support drag and zoom.